# Attribute capture not allowed on element input at this point

Tags: html

This line of code:

```
<input name="img" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" onchange="uploadImage(this, 75)" />
```

fails to pass the [W3C HTML5 validator](https://validator.w3.org/) check:

[image]
I would appreciate anyone letting me know why the error from W3C (and any solution), given that the code works fine and it opens the camera for mobile devices.

Comment: Post the code, too, not only an image of code. Also add the URL you've used for validation.

Comment: your code seems different from the code in the error message

Comment: @jochen: My bad. I edited the question for including the code as text (it was just in the screenshot) as *connexo* suggested and left a part behind. Thank you for reporting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a bug in the validator.

Even when the `capture` attribute didn't, so far, make its way into the [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sec-forms.html#the-input-element), it has already the "W3C Recommendation" status ([HTML Media Capture](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/)). Therefore, it should have been included in the validator.

On March 2018, an [issue was raised in the W3C mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator/2018Mar/0016.html) and a member of the validator team acknowledged it. It was fixed on [March 21, 2020](https://github.com/validator/validator/issues/933#issuecomment-602053518).

If you want to know more about the correct syntax regarding HTML Media Capture, have a look at [this article](https://blog.addpipe.com/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/).

Comment: Thanks @David for your explanation and editing my question above.

Comment: Thank you for the update @Colin'tHart, I was about to look for that info.

Answer (score -1):

```css
label.cameraButton {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em 0;

  /* Styles to make it look like a button */
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  border-color: #EEE #CCC #CCC #EEE;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

/* Look like a clicked/depressed button */
label.cameraButton:active {
  border-color: #CCC #EEE #EEE #CCC;
}

/* This is the part that actually hides the 'Choose file' text box for camera inputs */
label.cameraButton input[accept*="camera"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <label class="cameraButton">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
  </label>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I guess you mean `accept="image/*" capture="camera"`. If not, that is not a valid markup for the [`accept` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-input-accept)). Anyway, this fails to explain **why** the validator raise an error.